# Where do I buy items in D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

I want to play D&D but in the rule book it never said if I could buy items at any time or if you have to do it at a certain area. Do I have to buy it in a city or town? Can i buy it on the road?

Anything would help. Thanks!

Comment: What edition of D&D are you playing?

Comment: Also, are you the DM? Have you talked with your DM about this?

Comment: I am playing the starter set edition. I am not the DM and I have not talked to him about it.

Comment: Unfortunately “starter set” isn’t an edition. Fortunately that does narrow it down though, to either the 4th Edition or 5th Edition of the D&D rules. Do you remember what the cover of the starter set box looks like? Is it [this cover](https://rpggeek.com/image/796320/dungeons-dragons-starter-set) or [this cover](https://rpggeek.com/image/2073834/dungeons-dragons-starter-set)?

Comment: OK, I get the "tell me your edition" thing but this doesn't vary per rules edition, it varies per campaign (including stuff like Organized Play). I don't know that this really needs an edition to be reopened.

Comment: It definitely needs an edition. For example: In 5e, most magic items can never be bought at all, with a few notable exceptions like healing potions and some scrolls. In 4e, players are assumed to always have the ability to buy whatever magic items they want, since the magic item economy is so much more important for character balance.

Answer (score 3):

This is up to your DM and the setting you are in. Most characters will begin with a specific set of starting gear. After that, buying anything, magical or not, depends entirely on your setting and campaign.

I have one game I run where the players haven't been able to purchase anything, because the world is ending, and nobody is running shops. I have another I ran in the past where players were allowed to purchase magical items from a shop as early as level 2, since they were starting in a major city.

Comment: Yes, this is similar to how real life works. In New York City, you can buy nearly anything for which a price exists. In some small midwestern farming community, you can buy many common things and a handful of uncommon things. On top of a glacier in northern Alaska, maybe you can use your bag of shiny coins to distract a grizzly bear from eating you so quickly, or maybe not.

Comment: @user51154 I'm glad I could be useful, even if the question was put on hold.

Comment: You might note that certain campaigns like Organized Play may have built-in rules of their own around gear purchase (if, when, and how).